# DecodificarURL en Excel

Tags: excel, vba, url, formulas

Tengo un excel con unas variables que me han llegado de una URL y me vienen codificadas, ¿como puedo decodificarlas? Me da igual si es con formulas o con VBA, aunque no se como insertar dichos VBA de manera correcta para que funcionen. He tratado de insertar un script que he encontrado en Internet en la pestaña DESARROLLADOR y no he lograda nada excepto algunos errores.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres exactamente con decodificar? Quiza seria de ayuda que coloques algún registro de ejemplo (como texto) y lo que esperas obtener. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Excel no existe una funcion para decodificar URL, pero si es posible con una función personalizada, instalar un complemento de terceros o usar el comando substitute:

### Uso de una función VBA personalizada

Fuente: https://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/19/tutorial/how-to-bulk-decode-urls-excel.html
(buen tutorial con imágenes)

```
Public Function URLDecode(StringToDecode As String) As String

Dim TempAns As String
Dim CurChr As Integer

CurChr = 1

Do Until CurChr - 1 = Len(StringToDecode)
  Select Case Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr, 1)
    Case "+"
      TempAns = TempAns & " "
    Case "%"
      TempAns = TempAns & Chr(Val("&h" & _
         Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr + 1, 2)))
       CurChr = CurChr + 2
    Case Else
      TempAns = TempAns & Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr, 1)
  End Select

CurChr = CurChr + 1
Loop

URLDecode = TempAns
End Function
```

### Con complementos de terceros

Fuente: [SeoTools](https://seotoolsforexcel.com/urldecode/) (necesita instalación)

=UrlDecode(tu_texto_aqui)

### Con el comando SUSTITUIR (en inglés SUBSTITUTE)

Fuente: https://searchmarketingcorner.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/creating-an-excel-formula-to-encode-or-unencode-urls/

```
=SUSTITUIR(SUSTITUIR(SUSTITUIR(SUSTITUIR(SUSTITUIR(SUSTITUIR(SUSTITUIR(SUSTITUIR(SUSTITUIR(CELDA_A_DECODIFICAR,"%3F","?"),"%20"," "),"%25", "%"),"%26","&"),"%3D","="),"%7B","{"),"%7D","}"),"%5B","["),"%5D","]")
```